# if the function such $f(m+nf(m))=mf(n+1)$ find the f

Tags: functions, functional-equations

if $f:N^{+}\to N^{+}$,and such for any postive integer $m,n$ have
$$f(m+nf(m))=mf(n+1)$$
find the $f$

I guess this function is $f(n)=n$,But How to solve it?Thanks.

Comment: f(x)=0 satisfies the given equation but this is not a required function. Because codomain of f is $N^+$

Answer (score 3):

Following is rephrased solution by user **pslove** at corresponding [AoPS topic](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1791603p11855111) (also swapping $m,n$ to match OP).

Let $P(m,n)$ be the claim that $f(m+nf(m))=mf(n+1)$. Then for $n,a \in \mathbb{N}$ we have:

\begin{eqnarray*}
(n+af(n))f(f(n)+1)&=&f(n+af(n)+f(n+af(n))f(n))\hspace{10mm}&P(n+af(n), f(n))\\
&=&f(n+(a+nf(a+1))f(n))&P(n,a)\\
&=&nf(a+nf(a+1)+1)&P(n, a+nf(a+1))\\
&=&n(a+1)f(n+1)&P(a+1,n)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

This with little algebra gives
$$
\frac{nf(n+1)}{f(f(n)+1)}-f(n)=\frac{n-f(n)}{a+1}.
$$
Now right side has to be independent of $a$ for all $n$, which is only possible if $n-f(n)=0$. More specifically, if $n-f(n)\neq 0$ for any $n$, then for that particular $n$ being fixed, we can vary $a$, and both sides should vary, but we know left side is constant (with respect to fixed $n$).

So $f(n)=n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Function $f(x)$ is defined on the countable set of points and can be considered as the countable sequence of values
$$\{f(1),f(2),f(3),\dots\},$$
with the system of the equations
$$f(nf(m)+m) = mf(n+1),\quad (m,n)\in \mathbb N^2. \tag1$$

Let us research the structure of this sequence.

The value $f(1)=p$ should satisfy the system of
$$f(np+1) = f(n+1),\quad n\in \mathbb N.\tag2$$

If $\mathbf{p=1}$ then the equation $(1)$ is satisfied for each value of $n$.

If $\mathbf{p>1}$ then $f(x)$ is a periodic function with the period $p$,
$$f(m+p) = f(m).\tag3$$

At the same time, the value $f(2)=q$ should satisfy the system of
$$f(f(m)+m) = mq,\quad m\in \mathbb N.\tag4$$

In particular, for the values $m\in\{1,2,1+q,1+q+q^2,1+q+q^2+q^3\dots\},$
$$\begin{cases}
f(p+1)=q\\
f(2+q) = 2q\\
f(2+q+q^2) = 4q\\
f(2+q+q^2+q^3) = 8q\\
\dots.
\end{cases} \tag5$$

If $f(1) = p>1,$ then the system $(4)$ contradicts with the periodiity condiion $(2).$

If $f(1) = p = 1,$ then for $m=1$ from $(1)$ should the identity
$$f(n+1) = f(n+1).\quad n\in\mathbb N,$$

then $f(1) = 1.$

Since $f(x)$ is a countable set of points, it can be presented in the polynomial form of
$$f(x) = 1+a_1(q-1)(x-1)+a_2(q-1)^2(x-1)^2+...,\quad a_i\in \mathbb R.\tag6$$
wherein from $(5)$ should
$$\begin{cases}
1+a_1(q-1)+a_2(q-1)^2+a_3(q-1)^3+\dots = q\\
1+a_1(q^2-1)+a_2(q^2-1)^2+a_3(q^2-1)^3+\dots = 2q\\
1+a_1(q^3-1)+a_2(q^3-1)^2+a_3(q^3-1)^3+\dots = 4q\\
1+a_1(q^4-1)+a_2(q^4-1)^2+a_3(q^4-1)^3+\dots = 8q\\
\dots\\
1+a_1(q^{k+1}-1)+a_2(q^{k+1}-1)^2+a_3(q^{k+1}-1)^3+\dots = 2^kq\\
\dots.
\end{cases}\tag7$$

Transitional limit $k\to \infty$ leads to the solution
$$q=2,\quad a_1=1,\quad a_2=a_3=\dots =0,$$
$$f(x)= x.\tag8$$

Substitution of $(8)$ to $(1)$ leads to the identity
$$nm+m=m(n+1).$$

Thus, $(8)$ is the single solution.

Comment: I'm confused. Once you get $f(1) = 1$, all that (1) tells you is $f(n+1) = f(n+1)$, right?

Comment: @mathworker21 You are right, thanks! Will be fixed.

Comment: @mathworker21 Ready.Thanks, once more.

Comment: "Since () is a countable set of points, it can be presented in the polynomial form of
()=1+1(−1)(−1)+2(−1)2(−1)2+...,∈ℝ" is complete nonsense.

Comment: @mathworker21 q=const.

Comment: Try giving a proof for that expansion. I'm letting you know, it won't go well

Comment: @mathworker21 Any finite set of points can be described via the polynomial (for example, Lagrange interpolation polynomial). I've used Taylor presentation for it. Also, the polynomial coefficents were multiplied to unzero constants.

Comment: You can't go from finite to infinite. Like I said, try writing out a completely rigorous proof. You will fail.

Answer (score -1):

If we set $n=0$, you get that for every $m \in N^+$, $$f(m)=mf(1).$$
So we just have to find $f(1)$. Fixing $m$ and $n$ and using the last equality, 
\begin{align*}
f(m+nf(m)) &= f(m+nmf(1))\\
&=(m+nmf(1))f(1),
\end{align*}
now because $f(m+nf(m))=mf(n+1)=m(n+1)f(1)$, we get that $(m+nmf(1))f(1)=m(n+1)f(1).$ Simplifying the last equality, we see that $f(1)^2 = 1$; because $f$ is restricted to be positive then $f(1)=f(1)$ and $f(n)=n$ for very $n\in N^+$.

Answer (score -6):

$f(m+nf(m))=mf(n+1)
$

Putting $n=0$,
this becomes
$f(m) = mf(1)
$.

Putting $k=f(1)$
so $f(n) = kn$,
this becomes
$k(m+kmn) = mk(n+1)
$
or
$1+kn = n+1
$
so
$k=1$.

---

If $f(n) = an+b$ then

$a(m+n(am+b))+b=m(a(n+1)+b)
$
or
$am+a^2mn+abn = amn+am+bm
$
or
$a^2mn+abn 
= amn+bm
= m(an+b)
$
or
$abn
=m(an+b-a^2n)
$

Putting $n=1$,
this is
$ab = m(a+b-a^2)
$.

The left side is
independent of $m$,
and the right side is not
if $a+b-a^2 \ne 0$.

Therefore
$ab = a+b-a^2 = 0$
so
$b = a^2-a$
and
$0 = a(a^2-a)
=a^2(a-1)
$.

If $a=0$
then $b=0$.
Otherwise
$a=1, b=0$.

Therefore the only linear solutions are
$0$ or $n$.

Comment: The OP specifies $n$ should be a positive integer

Comment: I never took $f(0)$.

Comment: No, but you set $n = 0$.

Comment: So what. $m \ge 1$ is all that is needed. Both $m+nf(m) \ge 1$ and $n+1 \ge 1$.

Comment: All that matters is the parameter of $f$. How that comes to be does not matter as long as it is least 1.

Comment: "for any postive integer $m,n$ have..."

Comment: It's not just argument to $f$. It's the domain of validity of the functional equation.  (I didn't downvote though.)